# Read Images programmatically

Tags: c#, php

i am a 3rd year computer science student, and my seminar(graduation project) is in the next semester, so i started to think about it and i thought that a face recognition system would be a great idea, so i have two questions:

1- how can i read a picture programmatically, i mean if i have a picture, how can read the pixels and colors in order to recognize the face later on?

2- do you know any useful ebooks or resources that might help me in this topic cuzz i am really interested about it, and i hope that i can implement it.

thank you very much dudes

**this is my first post and i hope you will really help me :)**

Comment: By "have a picture", do you mean you have an image file, e.g. a JPEG or a PNG?

Comment: yes i will use the webcam to capture the photos (JPG,JPEG)

Comment: Voted to close for "overly broad". You can't expect an education in image processing in a few posts here.

Comment: Both C# and PHP already have libraries that can read various image formats.  For instance, see http://php.net/manual/en/book.image.php for PHP.

Comment: thanks a lot, i'll see right now, i'll read about image processing

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at [OpenCV](http://sourceforge.net/projects/opencv/) which makes access to webcams easy! It can also help you with further picture computations.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [AForge.NET](http://www.aforgenet.com/) library. This library has very usefull API for computer vision. Take a look also on [articles](http://www.codeproject.com/script/Articles/MemberArticles.aspx?amid=1181072) writen by author of this library - Andrew Kirillov. He wrote about motion detection algorithms and hand gesture recognition.

Comment: thank you, i am taking a look on it right now, i appreciate your contribution